# Listing all repositories using GitHub - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my script in C#. I've tried list all public repositories in GitHub.

Here is my code:

```
             HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Proxy = null;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                content1= reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

And i have error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
 The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
 Source=System


An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
```

on line with using....

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the full exception message (including any inner exceptions you can see).

Comment: Full Exception: Additional information: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364") as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = "TestApp";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        content1= reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Use UserAgent because when you request from Browser your url serve data but when application it is not server and UserAgent is problem. Though you can see same error with some other parameter missing as well.